# Overlay layout from top Android

Tags: android, xml, drawerlayout

I'm having a design idea but I have no clue how to actually code it. Basically, think of three `views`: `toolbar`, `view_overlay` and `main_view`

I want the following to happen: when a button is clicked in `toolbar`, the `view_overlay` (invisible at first) slides from top and overlays on the main view. The top of `view_overlay` and bottom of `toolbar` are touching. The main view is blackened (50 percent) and/or blurred as the `view_overlay` comes down. view_overlay's height may be less than `main_view`'s height.
Finally, pressing the back button would trigger the `view_overlay` to disappear by sliding to the top.

How can I start to build this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) for the `view_overlay`.  Also, you may have to write some custom layout/animation code for effect and alignment you were describing.

Comment: how about blackening the main_view as the view_overlay moves down?